# dlopen - cannot open shared object file

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, visibility, dlopen, dlsym

I'm compiling a shared library with gcc and loading it using dlopen. I also pass the following to the compiler:

```
-fvisibility=hidden
```

When I compile the library WITHOUT the visibility flag, everything works perfectly. However, when I compile WITH the flag, I get the following error with dlopen:

```
libtest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The linbrary .so file exists! This seems weird to me, since if some symbols are hidden, I would expect dlsym to fail if something cannot be found. However, this already fails when loading the library (aka dlopen).

I also tried adding

```
__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
```

to the functions I later call (extern "C"), without any success. Does anyone know what I can do about this? Or alternatively, is there any way to debug this to figure out why dlopen fails? I do not want to remove the visibility flag, since his drastically reduces my executable size.

Comment: Can you run with `LD_DEBUG=all` and report your findings?

Comment: Thanks. My shared lib was depended on another lib that could not be found. Thanks for LD_DEBUG, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

My lib was depended on another lib that could not be found.

---

You may use [ldd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) to see the list of all dependencies, including missing.

```
ldd libtest.so
```